# How to create new column based on another column's contents in R

Tags: r

This is a sample of my data set:

```
>data
C1         C2   C3  C4  C5  C6  
ATOM    1   -4.794  -7.29   6.756   C
ATOM    1   -4.357  -6.181  6.473   O
ATOM    2   -5.878  -8.511  5.233   C
ATOM    2   -7.02   -9.179  5.732   C
ATOM    3   -7.479  -9.499  6.108   C
ATOM    5   -4.873  -7.021  6.767   C
ATOM    8   -3.891  -6.723  6.31    O
ATOM    1   -7.515  -10.402 -0.621  C
ATOM    1   -7.26   -11.716 -0.22   O
ATOM    2   -7.53   -10.348 0.581   C
ATOM    3   -6.689  -11.008 2.344   C
```

Ultimately, What I want to achieve is to have a new column that detects when the numbers in C2 reset back to 1, as shown below:

```
>data
C1         C2   C3  C4  C5  C6    C7    
ATOM    1   -4.794  -7.29   6.756   C     1
ATOM    1   -4.357  -6.181  6.473   O     1
ATOM    2   -5.878  -8.511  5.233   C     1
ATOM    2   -7.02   -9.179  5.732   C     1
ATOM    3   -7.479  -9.499  6.108   C     1
ATOM    5   -4.873  -7.021  6.767   C     1
ATOM    8   -3.891  -6.723  6.31    O     1
ATOM    1   -7.515  -10.402 -0.621  C     2
ATOM    1   -7.26   -11.716 -0.22   O     2
ATOM    2   -7.53   -10.348 0.581   C     2
ATOM    3   -6.689  -11.008 2.344   C     2
```

I used a for loop with a nested if statement. My method was to compare an existing row with the following row. if the value is less than/ equal to the existing value, I assign 1 to the new column - if not, I increment the old count by 1.

```
C7 = NULL
i <- 1
index <- 1

for ( i in 1:nrow(data)){ 
  if(data$C2[i] <= data$C2[i+1]){
     data$C7 = index
  } else {
    data$C7 <- index + 1
  }
}


**This code doesnt work and this error occurs 
  Error in if (data$C2[i] <= data$C2[i + 1]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed **
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong and have a feeling that there's an even better way to do this. I appreciate any help -- thank you in advance!

Comment: the problem is that the for loop goes to the end of the column and then looks for the end + 1 which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop:

```
data$C7 <- c(1, cumsum(diff(data$C2) < 0) + 1)


     C1 C2     C3      C4     C5 C6 C7
1  ATOM  1 -4.794  -7.290  6.756  C  1
2  ATOM  1 -4.357  -6.181  6.473  O  1
3  ATOM  2 -5.878  -8.511  5.233  C  1
4  ATOM  2 -7.020  -9.179  5.732  C  1
5  ATOM  3 -7.479  -9.499  6.108  C  1
6  ATOM  5 -4.873  -7.021  6.767  C  1
7  ATOM  8 -3.891  -6.723  6.310  O  1
8  ATOM  1 -7.515 -10.402 -0.621  C  2
9  ATOM  1 -7.260 -11.716 -0.220  O  2
10 ATOM  2 -7.530 -10.348  0.581  C  2
11 ATOM  3 -6.689 -11.008  2.344  C  2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @SvenHohenstein. I'm also having problems with C6 -I have for loop with nested if to set C8 to code below. However this doesn't work. do you have any suggestions?                          for (i in nrow(data2)){                                               if (data2$C6[i] == "N"){
 data2$C8[i] = 12
} else if(data2$C6[i] == "O"){ 
 data2$C8[i] = 14
} else if(data2$C6[i] == "N"){ 
  data2$C8[i] = 16
}}

Comment: @user3321645 Why are there two `N`s. Do you want one `C` instead?

Comment: i'm sorry didn't realize its a typo, @SvenHohenstein
  
 for (i in nrow(data2)){ if (data2$C6[i] == "N"){ data2$C8[i] = 12 } else if(data2$C6[i] == "O"){ data2$C8[i] = 14 } else if(data2$C6[i] == "C"){ data2$C8[i] =16}}. Even so, the code doesn't work properly.

Comment: @user3321645 You can try `data$C8 <- ifelse(data$C6 == "N", 12, ifelse(data$C6 == "O", 14, 16))`.

Comment: your code works just fine! I was not aware about utilizing ifelse() function the way you did. I'm used to programming in C++ so that's why I've for loops every time i want to read data in an array. I appreciate your help!